# Custom headers with HTML5 video requests

Tags: html, video, oauth

I have a video resource sitting behind OAuth 2.0 wall and want to display it via `<video>` tag. How can I send `Authorization` header with video requests?

Answer (score 5):

i had this problem and sent Authorization token in url query parameter like this (server side code must be changed to allow reading Token From both request header & request query parameter) :  `http://www.example.com/samplevideo?Authorization=sample_token`

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you can't.

But you can still use the [`error` attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/media-elements.html#mediaerror) to check if the `<audio>` element can fetch the video from JavaScript, and redirect to an authentication page if not.

Comment: Authentication status is not a problem. I already have a token, but need to attach it to the video request. I can't fetch video data with an AJAX request.